# How to draw rectangles with cartesian axes and dimensional constraints in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw exactly the same figure attached using Tikz-PGF package in lateX. How can I do that. I appreciate any help, because I have to submit a paper, and it was kind of last minute addition. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This service "do-it-for-me" ...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->]  (-1,0.0) -- (6,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[<->]  (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[below left] {$y$};

\draw[very thick]   (0,0) |- (5,1) -- (5,0)
                    (2,0) |- (3,2) -- (3,0);
\draw[{Bar[width=4mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=4mm]}]
    (2,-0.4) -- node[fill=white] {$W$}  (3,-0.4);
\draw[{Bar[width=4mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=4mm]}]
    (0,-0.8) -- node[fill=white] {$GW$} (5,-0.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That above code will work, you need to preamble add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}`. Result:

[image]

**Addendum:**
As request in comment below ... follows three cases of possible coloring of "rectangles":

[image]

Complete small document, called Minimal Working Example (MWE), which produce above images, is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
% colored lines
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->]  (-1,0.0) -- (6,0) node[below left] {$x$};
    \draw[<->]  (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[below left] {$y$};

\draw[red,very thick]  % <--- changed
                (0,0) |- (5,1) -- (5,0); 
\draw[blue,very thick] % <--- added 
                (2,0) |- (3,2) -- (3,0); 

    \draw[{Bar[width=4mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=4mm]}]
        (2,-0.4) -- node[fill=white] {$W$}  (3,-0.4);
    \draw[{Bar[width=4mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=4mm]}]
        (0,-0.8) -- node[fill=white] {$GW$} (5,-0.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
% colored lines and fill
    \draw[<->]  (-1,0.0) -- (6,0) node[below left] {$x$};
    \draw[<->]  (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[below left] {$y$};

\draw[draw=red,fill=red!30,very thick]   % <--- changed
                (0,0) |- (5,1) -- (5,0); 
\draw[draw=blue,fill=blue!30,very thick] % <--- added
                (2,0) |- (3,2) -- (3,0); 

    \draw[{Bar[width=4mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=4mm]}]
        (2,-0.4) -- node[fill=white] {$W$}  (3,-0.4);
    \draw[{Bar[width=4mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=4mm]}]
        (0,-0.8) -- node[fill=white] {$GW$} (5,-0.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
% colored lines and fill, added transparency
    \draw[<->]  (-1,0.0) -- (6,0) node[below left] {$x$};
    \draw[<->]  (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[below left] {$y$};

\draw[draw=red,fill=red!30,very thick,semitransparent]  % <--- changed  
                (0,0) |- (5,1) -- (5,0); 
\draw[draw=blue,fill=blue!30,very thick,semitransparent]% <--- changed
                (2,0) |- (3,2) -- (3,0); 

    \draw[{Bar[width=4mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=4mm]}]
        (2,-0.4) -- node[fill=white] {$W$}  (3,-0.4);
    \draw[{Bar[width=4mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=4mm]}]
        (0,-0.8) -- node[fill=white] {$GW$} (5,-0.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand why you said that. I've never done this before. But searching for doing this took me all morning, and I couldn't find the answer. Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: Is it possible to color each rectangular alone?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. just line: `draw=color` or fill `fill=color`. I add examples of three coloring.